# Swift Face ID saving login credentials

Tags: swift, face-id

Im currently building an iOS app that requires users to sign in using a username,passsword, and company ID. Customers would like to be able to sing in through Face ID. How can I associate each user with its faceID? How can I access their sign in information for each individual user

Comment: You completely misunderstand how Face ID or Touch ID comes into play when the user signs in their account.

Answer (score 2):

FaceID is just a convenient replacement for the 4 or 6 digit system pass code, nothing else.

What you can do – like many third party apps – provide a login window to authenticate with username and password, save the credentials in the keychain and enable FaceID. On the second login the user *unlocks* the app with FaceID and the app reads the credentials from the keychain.

Comment: What if a user deletes the app. and reinstalls it again. will the credential be still in the keychain?

Comment: @AbdulMomen Honestly I don't know

Comment: Yes, the credentials will still be in the keychain. The keychain lives on the system / iCloud, not as a part of your app

Answer (score 0):

```
enum BiometricType {
  case none
  case touchID
  case faceID
}

func biometricType() -> BiometricType {
  let _ = context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil)
  switch context.biometryType {
  case .none:
    return .none
  case .touchID:
    return .touchID
  case .faceID:
    return .faceID
  }
}
```

Also Please follow https://www.raywenderlich.com/236-how-to-secure-ios-user-data-the-keychain-and-biometrics-face-id-or-touch-id#toc-anchor-007 for details Info.
Thanks